# React context value is not defined in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I'm using React and Context API to store the userId in a Context.

A component **Authenticator** is under my **ContextProvider** and store the userId in the context, it's working very well.

However, i want to use this userId from the context in another component **MySpace** in order to fetch some data about the current user. But in the ComponentDidMount() function of **MySpace**, this.context.userId is null. I think it's because my ContextProvider is doing a setState() to store userId and **MySpace** is mounted before the setState() has finished.

Here is my code, i don't know if i need to fetch data in another lifecycle method or so.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <UserContextProvider>
                    <Authenticator />
                    <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
                        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                        <PrivateRoute path='/my-space' component={MySpace} />
                        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
                    </Switch>
                </UserContextProvider>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

UserContext.js

```
export const UserContext = createContext();

class UserContextProvider extends React.Component {
    state = {
        userId: null
    }

    replaceUser = (userId) => {
        this.setState({ userId: userId });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={{...this.state, replaceUser: this.replaceUser}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Authenticator.js

```
class Authenticator extends Component {
    static contextType = UserContext;

    componentDidMount() {
        const { replaceUser } = this.context;
        replaceUser(getUserId());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <></>
        );
    }
}
```

MySpace.js

```
class MySpace extends Component {
    static contextType = UserContext;

    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = "Mon espace - Todo";
        this.getMyProjects();
    }

    getMyProjects = () => {
        const { userId } = this.context
        console.log(userId) // => null 
        _getMyProjects(userId)
            .then(projects => {
                console.log(projects)
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>Mon espace</p>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could catch when the ContextProvider ahs the userId and is ready to fetch the data just need another prop in your state in my example ive used **isReady**

```
export const UserContext = createContext();

class UserContextProvider extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isReady: false,
        userId: null
    }

    replaceUser = (userId) => {
        this.setState({ userId: userId, isReady: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={{...this.state, replaceUser: this.replaceUser}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

And in byour MySpace Component you need to check in componentDidUpdate if the isReady flag is true you can fetch the data with the userID:

```
class MySpace extends Component {
    static contextType = UserContext;

    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = "Mon espace - 
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
     if(this.context.isReady){
       this.getMyProjects();
     }
    }


    getMyProjects = () => {
        const { userId } = this.context
        console.log(userId) // => null 
        _getMyProjects(userId)
            .then(projects => {
                console.log(projects)
            })
            .catch(err => alert(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>Mon espace</p>
        )
    }
}
```

I think that this could solve your issue, othe approach could be instead of creating a new prop just check if the context **userId** is different from null as **null** is your initial state

Comment: Thank you, with the 'isReady' var it's working !
But I have another problem now, in MySpace.js I've added a state with an array of data, when I fetch the data in getMyProjects() and do a setState() with them the ComponentDidUpdate() is called and there is an infinite loop ...

Comment: You can handle this checking if the isREady is true and your array is empty excecute getMyProject() like this in componentDidUpdate:  ````if( this.context.isReady && ( Your list is empty ) ){ getMyProject() }````

Comment: Great!, if this worked just remember to accept the answer as correct ! :)